# TypeScript Generic Constraint on Function

Tags: typescript, generics, constraints, typescript-generics

I have an interface with routes and responses of an API which looks like this (partially):

```
interface Responses {
    [api.GetEntityOne]: EntityOneResponse;
    [api.GetEntityOneByID]: EntityOneByIDResponse;
    ...
}
```

(`api.<X>` is just an enum with the routes)

All responses extend either `GetObject<T>` or `GetArray<T>` as described below.

```
interface GetObject<T> {
   ...
   data: T;
}

interface GetArray<T> {
   ...
   data: T[];
}
```

E.g:

```
interface EntityOneResponse extends GetArray<{
    id: number;
    name: string;
}> {}

interface EntityOneByIDResponse extends GetObject<{
    id: number;
    detailedInfo: {
        ...
    }
}> {}
```

Now I want to make a function which only accepts routes which return a response which extends the `GetArray<T>` interface. In this function I want to fetch all entities and concat them in a long array (the API only allows max 200 items per call), but I can't get the generic constraint right.

I want a constraint so the function accepts 1 parameter, the route,  but only routes which are present in the `Responses` interface ánd which return a response which extends `GetArray<T>`.

My attempts thus far include:

```
// Doesn't work because it accepts all routes although it returns `never` for routes which do not extend `GetArray<T>`.
function getAllClientEntities<Y extends keyof Responses, T = Responses[Y] extends GetArray<any> ? Y : never>(route: Y): T;

// Doesn't accept a single route
function getAllClientEntities<R extends keyof Responses, Y extends Responses[R] extends GetArray<any> ? R : never>(route: Y);

// Accepts all routes
function getAllClientEntities<Y extends keyof Responses, T = Responses[Y] extends GetArray<any> ? Y : never>(route: T);
```

And I've tried more versions, but most didn't come even close. I was wondering if someone could help?

Comment: I think if the issue you're having is related to the "accepts the wrong thing", you should look into the "extends keyof Responses" part. Also I don't understand why you wrapped it in square brackets in the `Responses`, basically declaring those as an array? I think it would make sense but in a different way, see: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures

Comment: It should extend keyof `Responses`, but not all keys, so there has to be an extra constraint. The square brackets can be used in TypeScript to access a key in an interface with a type. (e.g.: `interface MyType { key: string }; type Derived = MyType["key"]; // Dererived = string`.

Comment: The extra constraint could be declaring a new type for each Response. I think you're making it too complicated. Also, I meant Reponses in the interface declaration not when you're extending the Type in the function parameter (which, again is overcomplicating things)

Comment: The brackets in the interface declaration are used so an enum-value can be used as key in the interface. If you have a variable which is being used as key (whether it is in a type or a value), the variables has to be wrapped in square brackets.

Comment: If the type of the indexing key matches the one inside the square brackets it will map. It has nothing to do with enums, it could be a string, integer, etc. Please read the link I shared. I would start by removing all the "extends" and seeing exactly what types you're defining for the function parameter and return and working your way up from a simpler implementation.